# Nodejs identify client ssl

Tags: node.js, https

I have a Node js backend. I use OAuth 2 for authentication. All the endpoints are secured by this authentication method except one endpoint. I cannot use OAuth in this insecure endpoint because the endpoint is triggered by another server on which I don't have any control. So I cannot tell the other server to send me a token for my backend to validate.

The request to my backend is made with SSL connection. So, in Nodejs is there any way to find out the SSL issuer name or something like that so that my backend can validate the requester? (All the requests to my insecure endpoint comes from the same server)